# C# log parser uses original user after impersonating

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation, logparser

I'm trying to impersonate a windows service as a different user in order to execute a remote log parser query.

The impersonation seems to work, as the following variables contain the new user:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
Environment.UserName
```

However the log parser executes with the original user:

```
rsLP = LogParser.Execute(strSQL, EVTlog);
```

I tried a few combinations of logon types and providers, but none of them was successful. :/

When i run it not as a service- it works.
Any idea why?

Comment: Is the impersonated account a domain account, in the same domain as the remote computer?

Comment: @GabrieleGiuseppini Yes (sorry for the late response).